# How to upload tar.gz and jar files as GitHub assets using python requests?

Tags: python, github, python-requests, github-api

In a certain directory, I have one .tar.gz and one .jar artifact.  I want to upload these assets for a release using requests.   Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.

Assuming that this .tar.gz file was called peaches.tar.gz here is what I tried doing:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/gzip'}
myAuth = {'MyGithubName', 'myToken'}
requests.post('https://api.github.com/repos/MyGithubName/MyRepo/releases/SomeIDNumber/assets?name=peaches.tar.gz, auth= myAuth, headers= headers, data= open('peaches.tar.gz', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Github documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset), to upload an asset you need the `upload_url` :

```
POST https://<upload_url>/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets?name=foo.zip
```

You will need to extract this url from the [get release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) (list releases, get a single release or get latest release). You can find [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release) :

> Note: This returns an upload_url key corresponding to the endpoint for
> uploading release assets. This key is a hypermedia resource.

The upload url is an [URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) such as :

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/ustream-dl/releases/8727946/assets{?name,label}
```

To build it, you can use [uritemplate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uritemplate) module & expand the `name` property (also described [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia))

The following will get the latest release and upload `peaches.tar.gz` asset to it (with name `peaches.tar.gz`) :

```
import requests 
from uritemplate import URITemplate

repo = 'bertrandmartel/ustream-dl'
access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/{0}/releases/latest'.format(repo))

upload_url = r.json()["upload_url"]

t = URITemplate(upload_url)
asset_url = t.expand(name = 'peaches.tar.gz')

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/gzip',
    'Authorization': 'Token {0}'.format(access_token)
}
r = requests.post(
    asset_url, 
    headers = headers, 
    data = open('peaches.tar.gz', 'rb').read()
)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```